# AWS EC2 User Data not working (Tried Installing and starting httpd via User Data)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The Following is my EC2 User Data:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sudo yum update -y

sudo yum install -y httpd

sudo systemctl start httpd

sudo systemctl enable httpd
```

In Security Group SSH 22 Port and HTTP 80 Port is Open.

Yet when I try accessing `http://public_ip_of_instance` the HTTP Apache page doesn't load.

Also, on the Instance Apache is not installed when I checked `sudo systemctl status httpd`.

I then manually tried it on the EC2 Server and it worked. Then I removed it through `yum remove` as I wanted to see whether User Data works.

I stopped the Instance and started again but I observed that the User Data Script doesn't work as I am unable to access http page through browser and also on Instance http is not installed.

Where is the actual issue? Some months back this same thing worked on another instance I remember.

Comment: You need to check `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` for the log of the user-data execution to determine what the issue is.

Comment: The User Data script is only executed the **first time** that an instance starts. It will _not_ run when subsequently started. This is intentional, since the script is intended to be used for installing software on first boot only.

Answer (score 1):

For all those who will run into this problem, first of all check the log with the command:

```
sudo cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log
```

then if you notice connection errors to the various repositories, the reason is because you don't have an internet connection. However, if once inside your EC2 you manage to launch the update and install commands, then the reason why they fail in the UserData is because your EC2 takes a few seconds to get the Internet connection and executes the commands before having it. So to solve this problem, just add this command after #!/bin/bash

```
#!/bin/bash
until ping -c1 8.8.8.8 &>/dev/null; do :; done
sudo yum update -y
...
```

This will prevent your EC2 from executing commands before an internet connection is established

Answer (score 0):

Your user data is **correct**. Whatever is happening with your website is not due to the user data code that you provided.

There could be many reasons it does not work. Public IP of the instance has changed, as always happens when you stop/start the instance. Instance may have per-existing software that clashes with httpd.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some general advice on running UserData once or each startup.

Short answer as John mentioned in the comments EC2's only run the UserData (aka Bootstrap) script once on initalization.

The user data Bash/Powershell is Infrastructure-As-Code. You deploy the script and it installs and configures the machine.

This causes confusion with everyone starting AWS. When you think about it though it doesn't make sense to run the UserData script each time when the PCs already been configured.

What people do often instead is make "Golden Images" (aka Amazon Machine Images - AMI's) of pre-setup EC2s, typically for PCs that take long time to install/configure. The beauty of this is you can setup AutoScaleGroups to use the images which saves any long installation during a scale up event.

Pro Tip: **When developing an UserData script run through and test it manually on the EC2**. Trust me its far quicker than troubleshooting unattended EC2 UserData errors.

Long answer: you can run the UserData on each boot of the machine using Mime  multi-part file. A mime multi-part file allows your script to override how frequently user data is run in the cloud-init package.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/